# Don't understand the behavior of the DBD::MySQL attribute "mysql_bind_type_guessing"

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

Why do I get this error when `mysql_bind_type_guessing` is enabled and why only with the argument "e" and not with the argument "a"?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.10.1;
use utf8;
use open qw(:utf8 :std);
use DBI;

my $user = '...';
my $passwd = '...';

my $dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:mysql:dbname=information_schema", $user, $passwd, {
    PrintError => 0,
    RaiseError => 1,
} ) or die DBI->errstr;

my $db = 'my_test_db';
$dbh->do( "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS $db" );
$dbh->do( "CREATE DATABASE $db" );
$dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:mysql:dbname=$db", $user, $passwd, {
    PrintError => 0,
    RaiseError => 1,
    AutoCommit => 1,
    mysql_enable_utf8 => 1,
    mysql_bind_type_guessing => 1,
} ) or die DBI->errstr;

my $table = 'Abteilung';
$dbh->do( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (
AbtNr      INT NOT NULL,
Name       VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY(AbtNr)
)" );

my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "INSERT INTO $table ( AbtNr, Name ) VALUES ( ?, ? )" );
my $abteilung_values = [
    [ 1, 'EDV'        ],
    [ 2, 'Verwaltung' ],
    [ 3, 'Chefetage'  ],
];
for my $row ( @$abteilung_values ) {
    $sth->execute( @$row );
}

$sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name REGEXP ?" );
$sth->execute( 'e' );
while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref() ) {
    say "@$row";
}
```

---

```
mysql_bind_type_guessing enabled

execute argument 'e':
# DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Unknown column 'e' in 'where clause' at ./perl3.pl line 46.

execute argument 'a':
# 2 Verwaltung
# 3 Chefetage


mysql_bind_type_guessing disabled

execute argument 'e':
# 1 EDV
# 2 Verwaltung
# 3 Chefetage

execute argument 'a':
# 2 Verwaltung
# 3 Chefetage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `mysql_bind_type_guessing` tries to guess whether your input data is numeric or not.  If the data is numeric, it won't quote it.

It appears that an inadequate check for numeric-ness is leading it to think that `e` is a number (`e` can be a part of numbers, such as `1.2e-3`).

Because it is not quoted, MySql tries to treat `e` as a column name instead, hence the error.

If my guess is correct, I would consider it a bug in `DBD::MySQL`.

**Update:** [Indeed, this is a bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=62458).